# managing 'cpu limit exceeded' for slow future jobs

Tags: apex, soql, future, cpulimit

So currently I have a future method that queries all the fields of an object and queries a large chunk of data, then does some nested for loops to map out field usage.

The problem is once it is used on objects with large amount of fields (700+), it hits CPU Exceeded limit time out of 10min. Not really too much wiggle room on code optimization.

From testing about 100 fields works fine, so i'm wondering if there is a way to queue this up to help avoid this issue?

I tried something like,

```
public void execute(    list<String> totalFields )
{

    List<List<String>> splitFields; // totalFields split up by 100 size.

    for(List<String> f: splitFields)
    {
       futuremethod(f);
    }
}
```

So it creates like 7 future jobs, but 4 of them times out, 3 succeeds. I'm curious if there is anything I can do programatically to get all the jobs to succeed, put some delays or timers or something to allow this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same using [Queueable apex](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_apex_queueable_chaining.htm), which will help in queuing multiple jobs one after the other asynchronously.